# Is there a way to call eventListner on any of multiple elements with same className or ID. Only the first child got called in my code

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener

devs.
I got stuck while building a project.
I have a list of menu items, about ten of them, with the same ID name and I will like to edit each of them if any
is clicked.
using js, I did this;

```
    
    const menuElement = document.querySelector('#menuElement')
    const darktheme = document.querySelector('.dark')

    loadEventListener()
    
    function loadEventListener() {
        menuElement.addEventListener('click', draw)
    }

    function draw() {
        menuElement.style.background = 'var(--primary-color)'
    }
```

However, when I click on the first menu element, it responds. but, it does not for the rest.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `.querySelectorAll` and then iterate over the found elements adding an eventlistener to each element. Note that `.querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` and not an `Array`.

Comment: "same className or ID" ... "same ID name" -- ids must be unique. Please show your HTML.

Comment: @Palladium02 Yes, that will work, but it's overkill. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to use a [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) and get all elements in the document that match that selector in a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). Then you could use [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) to attach an event listener to each of those elements.

Here a small working example.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e => {
  document.querySelectorAll(".myclass").forEach((element, i) => {
    element.addEventListener("click", () => console.log(`Div ${i} was clicked.`))
  });
})
```

```css
.myclass {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass">Div 0</div>
<div class="myclass">Div 1</div>
<div class="myclass">Div 2</div>
```

You should also wait for the DOM to be loaded before attaching event handlers using the [DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event).

> You **cannot** use an ID as IDs **must** be unique!

Another way to do it is using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) as outlined in [Scott Marcus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73391980/17487348).

Comment: Yes, this will work, but it's overkill. Instead of setting up an event handler for DOMContentLoaded, just place the script just before the closing `body` tag. And then instead of scanning the DOM for all the matching elements and then looping over each and assigning more event handlers, just use Event Delegation. With that there's just one event handler, no scanning the DOM and creating a collection and no loop (see my answer).

Comment: Yes, you're right. Added a remark to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But, instead of setting up multiple event listeners on all the elements you want, use ["Event Delegation"](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) and set up a single event listener on a common ancestor element, then let the event bubble up to that ancestor. In the event callback, you then check to see if the event originated at an element that you care to handle and, if so, handle it.

And note, that `id`s must be unique, however multiple elements can have the same class, so that's the way to go.

EXAMPLE:

```js
// Set up an event handler on a common ancestor
document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  // Check to see if the event originated at an element with the "foo" class
  if(event.target.classList.contains("foo")){
    // Handle the event any way you want
    event.target.classList.add("bold");
  }
});
```

```css
.bold { font-weight:bold; }
```

```html
<p>Clilck on any of the lines. Only the ones with the "foo" class will get bolded.</p>
<div class="foo">XYZ</div>
<div class="fooBar">XYZ</div>
<div class="foo">XYZ</div>
<div class="fooBar">XYZ</div>
<div class="foo">XYZ</div>
<div class="fooBar">XYZ</div>
```

Comment: I am curious: how is the performance of this approach on a large page with perhaps tens of thousands elements in its DOM? - intuitively, I'd be worried about this but have not looked into it (or done it this way myself)

Comment: @blurfus It's actually far superior to any other approach because the event is going to bubble anyway and, with this solution, there is only one event handler that needs to be set up, no scanning the DOM and no looping. The performance cost is essentially that of setting up one event handler.

Comment: @blurfus Additionally, while my example sets up the handler at the `document`, it doesn't have to be. Instead, you could wrap the elements you may want to handle in an element at a lower level in the DOM, so the event gets handled sooner.

Comment: Yes, that's what I normally do (wrap it in a lower, closer-to-the-action element) but I worried that setting up the handler at the document level would need to evaluate the entire DOM at run time (to account for dynamically added elements) and be very costly, performance-wise

Comment: @blurfus You may be a little confused. This approach doesn't evaluate the DOM at all. There is no `.querySelector(), .querySelectorAll()`, etc. used in this approach. All that happens in this approach is to leverage bubbling which is going to happen anyway. (Whether you handle a `click` event at the `document` or not, the event is still going to bubble up to it.) This approach doesn't add any new overhead, except one event handler that gets stored in memory and one `if` statement that checks for the existence of a class when the event is handled.

Comment: @blurfus And to be clear, when the event handler checks for the existence of a class, we're not scanning or evaluating the DOM, we're just checking the `event.target` that originated the event (and the event handler receives a reference to it) - - we don't go looking for it within the DOM, it triggers the event that is received and handled.

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation :)